# Bruteforcing with do... while or while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

The task is to guess 3 numbers: x, y  and z by only knowing sum of every two of them.

I suspect that multiple conditions might not work.

In this test case answer is obvious: every number is a 5, but for some reason the code does not work. It seems to perceive the task as resolved once sum of any variables is a 10.

```
var bruteforce = function(){
  var i = 0;
  var x = 0; //tie
  var y = 0; //jacket
  var z = 0; //shirt

  while (x+y !== 10 && z+y !== 10 && z+x !== 10){
    var x = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var y = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var z = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);  
    i++;
    }

   console.log('Solved at ' + i + ' attempts.');
   console.log('x =  ' + x);
   console.log('y =  ' + y);
   console.log('z =  ' + z);

};   

bruteforce();
```

Fiddle is here:  https://jsfiddle.net/9cpbfsof/2/

Comment: Why bruteforce? Use math! `x = (sum_xy+sum_xz-sum_yz)/2`.

Comment: @Oriol  Hm... If x+y=205; x+z=130; y+z=225, then proposed solution gives x as 110/2 = 55. The "bruteforce" suggested x is 40. It needed only 14,5M attempts, which is fun anyways :)

Comment: Then your brute force is wrong. The only solution is `x = 55`, `y = 150`, `z = 75`, see [Wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%2By%3D205,+x%2Bz%3D130,+y%2Bz%3D225). If `x=40`, it would mean `y=205-40=165` and `z=130-40=90`, but `165+90=255` instead of `225`.

Comment: ORLY? if x = 55 and y = 130 as you suggest, then x+y=185 which does not satisfy starting condition that x+y = 205. Bruteforce suggests answers: x = 40, y = 165, z = 90.

Comment: Right, I had a mistake, y+z=255 :)

Comment: I meant `y=150`, yes.

Answer (score 4):

You should use ORs (`||`) in your condition:

```
while (x+y !== 10 || z+y !== 10 || z+x !== 10){
    var x = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var y = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    var z = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);  
    i++;
}
```

Since your conditions are negative you want to keep going if any one of them fails. 
When using AND you stop if any of them succeeds. When using OR you stop once they all succeed.

Also I don't think you should use `var` inside your loop:

```
while (x+y !== 10 || z+y !== 10 || z+x !== 10){
    x = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    y = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    z = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);  
    i++;
}
```

*Record: 81 attempts :)*

Answer (score 0):

Once one condition satisfies loop ends, so it behaves as expected. Use || (OR) conditions in the while statement.